# Get Current Windows User VB.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net, iis-6, ldap

I have tried multiple ways of grabbing the username of a current logged on user in vb.net/asp.net.  I am running it on IIS 6 and understand that it will return NETWORK SERVICE for the username.  I need to grab the username of the actual windows box log on.

I have tried the following code: Returns NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

```
Dim User = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.User
Dim UserName = User.Translate(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  If I am unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set

```
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
 <identity impersonate="true" />
```

in `Web.config` to be able to do that.