# Recommended use of <identity impersonate="true"/> breaks application

Tags: vb.net, web-services, windows-authentication

[Get Current Windows User VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/754171/1357027)

Forgive this .NET rookie, for I know not the complexity of the application I am trying to support or the detailed workings of Windows Authentication.

The application I'm attempting to modify is a combination of an Excel Add-In and a Dynamics GP Web Service extension. I am attempting to add a simple line of code to the WS extension that sets the current windows user to a variable. Like the person in the linked question, I am getting NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and instead need to get the true windows user.

I came upon the Q&A in the above link. However, adding the line  to the WS extension web.config file breaks the application I'm working with. I receive an error beginning with "Client found response content type [...]" which continues below the viewable portion of the screen with no ability to scroll so I don't know if there is useful content further down.

I also have tried setting my variable to Environ("USERNAME") but that sets it to "ROGUE$" - ROGUE is my computer name. I am expecting a successful effort to result in my variable equal to "Administrator" as that is who I am on the virtual machine I'm testing on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an ASP.NET application in the context of a Windows user then you will need to use Windows authentication or change the identity which the application pool uses. This article: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/ASP-NET-3-5-Windows-Based-Authentication.id-310905.html looks to have the information you need for the former.

**Do consider the security implications** of doing that. It may be better to change permissions such that the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE user is allowed to do what is required *and no more*.

Further reading:

[Configuring ASP.NET Process Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc1xthy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Application Pool Identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)